# ValueError: shapes (20,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication, valueerror

I am a bit new to machine learning and am trying to do linear regression without using linear_model.LinearRegression() via sklearn. I think I am nearing the end of my coding and getting prepared to plot the line but I am getting the error "ValueError: shapes (20,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)". I printed out my 20 by 1 matrices to confirm and neither of them have any extra dimensions or anything so I'm not sure why it is giving me `(2,1)` in the error message or why the dimensions don't match up. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to "align" these matrices? I am using Python 3.5.1.

**Edit:**
I have looked at a lot of the other ValueError topics in stackoverflow but I am having trouble really understanding the recommendations. If possible, laymen's terms would be greatly appreciated.

Per Georgy I narrowed the code down to just the lines of code needed to cause the error message. `alpha`, `iters`, and `theta` were left alone to show all the variables required to be passed into the functions.

**Edit 2:** Alright, attempt 2 to reduce the example code. Thank you for working with me on this. I put a try-except statement around this line of code:

```
theta = theta -(alpha/len(X)) * np.sum((X @ theta.T - y) * X, axis=0)
```

Said line is nestled in a for loop using `i` as the variable. Said line is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YungL\Desktop\linearRegression.py", line 30, in <module>
    slope_and_intercept, cost = gradDescent(X_test, Y_test, theta, alpha, iters)
  File "C:\Users\YungL\Desktop\linearRegression.py", line 26, in gradDescent
    theta = theta -(alpha/len(X)) * np.sum((X @ theta.T - y) * X, axis=0)
ValueError: shapes (20,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Printing `X[i]`, `y[i]`, and `theta` when the exception is thrown gives me this respectively:

```
[[ 0.07786339]    [[233.]    [[1. 1.]]
```

Column 1 being `X`, column 2 being `y`, and column 3 being `theta`. Referencing the matrices, these are the 1st values in each matrix. Although for `theta`, that is the only value.

Here is the complete matrix of `X` and `y` at the time of the exception:

```
[[ 0.07786339]    [[233.]
 [-0.03961813]    [ 91.]
 [ 0.01103904]    [111.]
 [-0.04069594]    [152.]
 [-0.03422907]    [120.]
 [ 0.00564998]    [ 67.]
 [ 0.08864151]    [310.]
 [-0.03315126]    [ 94.]
 [-0.05686312]    [183.]
 [-0.03099563]    [ 66.]
 [ 0.05522933]    [173.]
 [-0.06009656]    [ 72.]
 [ 0.00133873]    [ 49.]
 [-0.02345095]    [ 64.]
 [-0.07410811]    [ 48.]
 [ 0.01966154]    [178.]
 [-0.01590626]    [104.]
 [-0.01590626]    [132.]
 [ 0.03906215]    [220.]
 [-0.0730303 ]]   [ 57.]]
```

Comment: Ideally your example should be something like: "For these `X`, `theta` and `y` the following code: `np.sum((X @ theta.T - y) * X, axis=0)` gives this error: ..."

Comment: Regarding your edit: we still can't run your code and reproduce the issue because you didn't provide `diabetes_data` and `diabetes`. But in fact we don't need them as you still can reduce your example. You can use [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to catch the moment when you have the error and print out the values of `X` and `y`. Then add them here.

Comment: You should've printed complete `X` and `y` because you use full arrays in that formula, not single elements of them. But we are getting close!

Comment: That was my 1st instinct too, dang I even had all the info in there and everything before just giving X[i] and y[i].

Comment: I suspect you want `X @ theta`, not `X @ theta.T`.

Comment: @Blckknght I don't think so. Shape of `X` and shape of `theta` are not equal (`(20,)` and `(2,)`). [Dot product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) won't work here. Probably they have mistake in the formula or in the definition of `theta`.

Comment: The exception message suggests that they're shaped `(20, 1)` and `(1, 2)` respectively, which can multiply together properly. Transposing the second one gives a shape of `(2, 1)`, which causes the exception. The printed values support these conclusions (`X` appears to be a long column, while `theta` has two elements in a single row).

Comment: So I removed the ``.T`` to test this out, I also had to remove the ``.T`` from this line of code: ``inner = np.power(((X @ theta.T) - y), 2)`` because it caused the same error. The program now runs but I just get a flat line outside of the data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrix multiplication (which is what the `@` operator does), you need the inner dimensions of the matrices in question to match. That is, you can multiply a 20 x 1 matrix by a 1 x 2 matrix, but not by a 2 x 1 matrix. This is not a `numpy` specific thing, it's just a basic fact of matrix arithmetic.

The issue you have is that `X @ theta.T` in your code is resulting in mismatched dimensions. I don't know what those variables represent (and you've edited the question to take out where they come from), but given the error, you probably want `X @ theta` instead. That will do the 20 x 1 and 1 x 2 multiplication, rather than the 2 x 1 multiplication that doesn't work mathematically.

Comment: Yes it seems like I may have an incorrect formula on how to get my linear regression. Removing the ``.T`` did get rid of the error I was encountering. However, unfortunately it looks like I'll have to go back to the beginning to figure out how to make the line I want.